# ASPX page has 2 hidden console errors - how to unhide?

Tags: asp.net, .net

Debugging an aspx page, the first thing I notice is two errors in Chome>Dev Tools> Console. However, going to the console command line, the errors are not displayed. If I hover over the "Red Check Icon" it says "Open in console to view two errors". What can I do to see the contents of these two errors?

[image]

Comment: You have "if (typeof PartLook)" in the filter. Did you try hitting the X next to that to clear your filter?

Comment: Yup, that's it. Thanks!